# TypeError: Cannot read property ‘visitStatement’ of undefined in angular2

Tags: angular, runtime-error

I am getting the following error in my angular2 application.

TypeError: Cannot read property ‘visitStatement’ of undefined

Answer (score 19):

You get this issue when you have an empty event handler,

```
(click)=""
```

Getting rid of the empty event handler will fix this issue.

**Ref:**

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3754
- http://hemanshubhojak.com/2016/07/04/angular2-cannot-read-property-visitstatement-of-undefined.html

Comment: seriously ng2 team, please provide better error handling, this is too criptic